# php insert data into two rows with array

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

I have a form like this. I wanted to save the form in ajax and the main thing is
the data entered here will be inserted as in 2 rows. 1 for the product a and the other for b.

(a and b are the names for the product which will be saved as a and b in the product name column)

```
<form class="product-data" action="">
    <table>
        <tr class="data-row">
            <td> 
                <input type="number" name="finance[a_source_unit]" >
            </td>
            <td >
                <input type="number" name="finance[a_target_unit]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="finance[a_client_price]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="finance[a_client_salary]" >
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="data-row">
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="finance[b_source_unit]" >
        </td>
        <td >
            <input type="number" name="finance[b_target_unit]">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="finance[b_client_price]">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="finance[b_client_salary]" >
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

My database is like this

```
id product_name source_unit target_unit client_price client_salary
```

So I made my ajax like this

```
var Table = $(this).closest('.product-data');
var data = Table.serializeArray();
data.push({name: 'action', value: 'save_product_data' });
$.post( ajaxUrl, data, function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
});
```

In the save_product_data function I have got the data like this

```
function save_product_data() {
    $finance = $_POST['finance'];
    print_r($finance);
}
```

The data is coming like this

```
Array
(
    [a_source_unit] => 3213
    [a_target_unit] => 123
    [a_client_price] => 34278
    [a_client_salary] => 7584
    [b_source_unit] => 3213234
    [b_target_unit] => 1234
    [b_client_price] => 34275438
    [b_client_salary] => 75854    

)
```

so basically I want that the values for a will be inserted in a row and b will be inserted in another row.

Comment: Your almost there, just add two insert query's in your ``save_product_data()`` function http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: I know how to save the data. I wanted to know how tosave them in two rows.

Comment: you can use multidimensional arrays like: `finance[b][client_salary]` in form file :) it'd much easier to create separated queries

Comment: @kmlnvm can you share some code?

Comment: @AgeDeO: w3fools is a crap resource. don't think to them. they have bad code and worse "advice".

Answer (score 0):

If you use a form like this one :

```
<form class="product-data" action="">
    <table>
        <tr class="data-row">
            <td> 
                <input type="number" name="finance[a][source_unit]" >
            </td>
            <td >
                <input type="number" name="finance[a][target_unit]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="finance[a][client_price]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="finance[a][client_salary]" >
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="data-row">
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="finance[b][source_unit]" >
        </td>
        <td >
            <input type="number" name="finance[b][target_unit]">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="finance[b][client_price]">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="finance[b][client_salary]" >
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

You'll have something like this in you `$_POST` array and you'll just have to use a foreach to insert row by row :

```
array
  'finance' => 
    array
      'a' => 
        array
          'source_unit' => string '5' (length=1)
          'target_unit' => string '5' (length=1)
          'client_price' => string '5' (length=1)
          'client_salary' => string '5' (length=1)
      'b' => 
        array
          'source_unit' => string '1' (length=1)
          'btarget_unit' => string '1' (length=1)
          'bclient_price' => string '1' (length=1)
          'client_salary' => string '1' (length=1)
```